# How to copy CComboBox data to another CComboBox?

Tags: mfc, visual-c++-6, ccombobox

How to copy CComboBox data to another CComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any supplied method to do so, other than use the usual methods (GetItemData, GetLBText, etc) to get the data from one and insert them into the other.